# ShinyDashboardPlus box sidebar opens behind objects inside box

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Why does the sidebar of the box open behind the `fileInput()` object? The box is from the `shinydashboardPlus` package. See picture and simple reproducible example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "midnight",
  header = dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
  sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
    minified = TRUE,
    id = "mysidebar",
    sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",
                menuItem(text = "Upload",
                         tabName = "tab_upload"))
  ),
  body = dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "tab_upload",
            fluidPage(
              box(
                title = "Upload files",
                status = "info",
                solidHeader = FALSE,
                width = 12,
                collapsible = TRUE,
                collapsed = FALSE,
                sidebar = boxSidebar(
                  id = "sb_uploadData",
                  background = "#f59e2d",
                  downloadButton(
                    "downlaod_templateData",
                    label = "Download template format",
                    icon = icon("download")
                  )
                ),
                "Upload files:",
                br(),
                br(),
                fluidRow(
                  column(4,
                         fileInput("dataUpload_1", "Upload 1", width = "400px")),
                  column(4,
                         fileInput("dataUpload_2", "Upload 2", width = "400px")),
                  column(4,
                         fileInput("dataUpload_3", "Upload 3", width = "400px"))
                )
              )
            ))
  )),
  title = "My Dashboard"
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `controlbar = dashboardControlbar(...)`

Comment: Indeed, good idea @YBS thanks. I'm just curious as to why this is happening.